# Read data from iceberg in AWS Glue Job

Tags: aws-glue

When I use glue to read a icebreg table,this is a error:

```
Unsupported dataframe format for job bookmarks
```

This is my script:

```
`hco_dynamic_dataFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
          database="cn_lastest",
          table_name="hco_data",
          transformation_ctx="hco_dynamic_dataFrame")`
```

I try to change add this parameters,but also get error

```
spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse=s3://veeva-od-delta-sync/cn_lastest/hco_data/
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.lock-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.DynamoLockManager
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.lock.table=hco_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method :

1. Enabled the Apache Glue Iceberg Connector as mentioned in section "Set up the Apache Iceberg connector and create the Iceberg connection" [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-the-aws-glue-connector-to-read-and-write-apache-iceberg-tables-with-acid-transactions-and-perform-time-travel/).
2. Sample Code as follows (Ensure Connector in #1 is added to your Glue Job) :

```js
import sys
import boto3
import json
import os
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from botocore.errorfactory import ClientError
import datetime
import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.AwsDataCatalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.AwsDataCatalog.warehouse", "<Any Warhouse dir>")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.AwsDataCatalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.AwsDataCatalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")
conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
conf.set("spark.sql.iceberg.handle-timestamp-without-timezone", "true")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session


## Read Input Table
IcebergDyF = (glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="marketplace.spark",connection_options={"path": "AwsDataCatalog.<Glue database>.<tablename>","connectionName": "<Set the same name as connection name set in the Glue Connection Point #1 above>",},transformation_ctx="IcebergDyF"))
IcebergSnapshotDyF = (glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="marketplace.spark",connection_options={"path": "AwsDataCatalog.etl_framework.etl_master.snapshots","connectionName": "<Set the same name as connection name set in the Glue Connection Point #1 above>",},transformation_ctx="IcebergSnapshotDyF"))

IcebergDyF.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("etl_master")
#IcebergDyF.show()

IcebergSnapshotDyF.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("etl_master_snapshots")

spark.sql(f"CALL AwsDataCatalog.system.expire_snapshots(table => 'etl_framework.etl_master',retain_last => 1)").show()

spark.sql(f"CALL AwsDataCatalog.system.rewrite_data_files(table => 'etl_framework.etl_master',options => map('rewrite-all','true'))").show()

spark.sql("CALL AwsDataCatalog.system.rewrite_manifests(use_caching => false, table => 'etl_framework.etl_master')").show()
```